# windows service file delete c#

Tags: c#

windows service example code

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
namespace file_delete
{
    public partial class file_delete : ServiceBase
    {  
        public file_delete()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {           
        }
        private void deleteFile(string folder)
        {
         System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(folder);
         System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");
           foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in fileNames)
           {              
               fi.Delete();               
           }
```

How can I call the **deleteFile(string folder)** from windows forms?

Comment: See: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1111/How-To-Host-NET-Remoting-Objects-in-Windows-Servic

You want to set up a channel so your form can "talk" to the service. .NET remoting is the least frinction, WCF + named pipes is probably better. 

Even if it looks like you are up to no good.

Comment: my I want to do  call deleteFile(file) method

Comment: @Phil. (You should post your comment as an answer)

Comment: @tgolisch Phil's comment beat me to it as I was writing mine, but I've said to same as him in an answer and included links to tutorials as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [OnCustomCommand](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/aa04e6/how-to-implement-oncustomcommand-method-in-windows-service-application/) override, but this only takes an integer as an argument and does not support passing strings to the service.

The other options would be to create a [WCF service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38160/WCF-Service-Library-with-Windows-Service-Hosting) or use [Remoting](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1111/How-To-Host-NET-Remoting-Objects-in-Windows-Servic) to pass the information you need to the service and call the delete method.

EDIT: to respond to a question in the comments about how to use OnCustomCommand in a very strange way is as follows.

In the service you would need something like this.

```
private const int CMD_INIT_DELETE = 1;
private const int CMD_RUN_DELETE = 0;

private bool m_CommandInit = false;
private StringBuilder m_CommandArg = new StringBuilder();

protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
{
    if (command == CMD_INIT_DELETE)
    {
        this.m_CommandArg.Clear();
        this.m_CommandInit = true;
    }
    else if (this.m_CommandInit)
    {
        if (command == CMD_RUN_DELETE)
        {
            this.m_CommandInit = false;
            this.deleteFile(this.m_CommandArg.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            this.m_CommandArg.Append((char)command);
        }
    }
}
```

In the windows form application you would have something like this

```
private const int CMD_INIT_DELETE = 1;
private const int CMD_RUN_DELETE = 0;

private void RunServiceDeleteMethod(string delFolder)
{
    serviceController1.ExecuteCommand(CMD_INIT_DELETE);

    foreach (char ch in delFolder)
        serviceController1.ExecuteCommand((int)ch);

    serviceController1.ExecuteCommand(CMD_RUN_DELETE);
}
```

THIS IS NOT TESTED and only a proof of concept. Again, I DO NOT recommend doing it this way and the above example is only to show how NOT to do this type of communications between desktop applications and services.

Comment: OnCustomCommand are those between 128 and 256. my send string

Comment: It can be any integer... I suppose you could if you REALLY wanted to, do a series of CustomCommand calls sending first the command to execute as a number (let's say 1) and then proceed to call the CustomCommand for each character in the file name and path followed by a 0 to indicate that you're done passing that info to the service. On the service end you could store this information and once a 0 is sent, call deleteFile with the filename you passed. I DO NOT suggest this though as it is very messy and why would you do it that way. It might be neat to try it, just to say that you've tried it.